# bundle install error activeadmin ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, activeadmin, ransack

Am trying to install my own project onto a secondary computer - both are macosx 10.8.4, both setup using macports and RVM.

For some reason as I'm trying to bundle install I'm getting this error:

```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ransack":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      ransack (>= 1.0.0) ruby

```
ransack (0.7.3)
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    ransack (>= 0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0.0) ruby

```
sass-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1)
```

```

Not sure why bundle install works fine on one computer and not the other; I recently participated in this ransack issue on with activeadmin on github and it seemed to be fixed; unsure why it's popping up again.

UPDATE: gem file:

```
            source 'https://rubygems.org'

            # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
            gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'

            # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
            gem 'sqlite3'

            # Use SCSS for stylesheets
            gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

            # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
            gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

            # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
            gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

            # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
            # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

            # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
            gem 'jquery-rails'

            # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
            gem 'turbolinks'

            # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
            gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

            gem 'ZenTest'

            # Add Foundation Here
            #gem 'compass-rails' # you need this or you get an err
            # gem 'compass-rails', github: 'milgner/compass-rails', branch: 'rails4'
            # gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0'

            gem 'paperclip',  '>= 3.4.0'  # image upload
            gem 'aws-sdk'



            # gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.1' 
            gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
                                          :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails',
                                          :branch => '3.0.0'

            gem 'devise',  github: 'plataformatec/devise'
            gem 'devise_security_extension', :github => 'phatworx/devise_security_extension' # security questions


            # administration
            gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
            gem 'ransack',             github: 'ernie/ransack',         branch: 'rails-4'
            gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
            gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'


            gem "rich", github: 'bastiaanterhorst/rich'

            # gem 'active_admin_editor'

            gem 'survey', :git => 'git://github.com/runtimerevolution/survey.git'

            # voting
            # gem 'acts_as_votable', github: 'ryanto/acts_as_votable' 
            gem "acts_as_votable", "~> 0.7.1"

            gem 'friendly_id', '5.0.0.beta4' # Note: You MUST use 5.0.0 or greater for Rails 4.0+

            group :doc do
              # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
              gem 'sdoc', require: false
            end

            # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
            # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

            # Use unicorn as the app server
            # gem 'unicorn'

            # Use Capistrano for deployment
            # gem 'capistrano', group: :development

            # Use debugger
            # gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

            group :development do
              gem 'better_errors'
              gem 'binding_of_caller'
              gem 'meta_request'
              gem 'rspec-rails'
              gem 'spork'
              gem 'spork-rails', :github => 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
              gem 'annotate'
            end

            group :test do
                gem 'rspec'
                gem 'autotest'
                gem 'autotest-growl'
                gem 'autotest-fsevent'
            end
```

Comment: Is your `Gemfile.lock` committed to version control? If not you should add it and then update your second computer. The `Gemfile.lock` is what guarantees that the same gem versions are used on all systems.

Comment: Ah; fairly new to ROR, had read somewhere else about deleting the Gemfile.lock in another thread; good info to have, thanks.

Comment: It's common for people on Stack Overflow to recommend deleting Gemfile.lock as a generic solution to Bundler problems, but IMO this is a bad idea. The point of the lock file is to make things consistent across machines, and that's almost always a good thing! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't want to use the `rails-4` branch of `ransack`. It looks like the current `master` version supports Rails 4.

The dependency on the `rails4` branch of `activeadmin` says that it needs `ransack` `>= 1.0.0`, but the version of `ransack` on the `rails-4` branch is `0.7.3`.

It is probably a better idea to use the released versions of gems from Rubygems unless you need specific unreleased fixes in the Git repo.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that was it. Must've been updated recently as read elsewhere that was the way of getting active admin up properly for 4.

Comment: Tim - strangely enough on the ORIGINAL computer I'm now having a problem where it's telling me to run bundle install, which I do, then try to run server, but it says devise (master) isn't checked out and to run bundle install as an endless loop.

Comment: Are you running the server using `bundle exec`? Maybe open up a new question with details of the new problem.